# how can I test the random read performance of storage system more quickly?

Tags: performance, storage, performance-testing, benchmarking, database-performance

The performance of random read is generally the lowest in a storage system, particularly in a write-optimized storage system.
So, how can I test the random read performance of a storage system more quickly? 
Can I only randomly read a certain percents of the records stored in a storage system? And how many percents of the records is usually tested?

Comment: Probably easiest to test for a fixed time interval, and see how many ops / how much data you read in that time.

Answer (score 0):

IOMeter should accomplish what you need, it should tell you what MB/Second your disk support

http://www.iometer.org/